# How to launch an Intent from a PlaceholderFragment?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch another activity from a fragment, but I'm getting an error that sais me "the class ... cannot be referenced from static context".

I'm doing the call from a handler, inside of a PlaceholderFragment

```
public void wait_launch_handler(int secs){

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Animation fadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadeout);
                rl_container.startAnimation(fadeout);

                Intent main_menu = new Intent(SplashscreenOptimizedActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(main_menu);
            }
    }, secs * 1000 );

}
```

The error is given by "Intent main_menu = new Intent(**SplashscreenOptimizedActivity.this**, MainActivity.class);"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside a Fragment you have to use `getActivity()` in place of `SplashscreenOptimizedActivity.this` to retrieve the context of the Activity that hosts your Fragment

Comment: Thanks, getActivity() makes the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Fragment.getActivity() method instead of SplashscreenOptimizedActivity.this

Comment: What I need to put in the place of Fragment? getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment().getActivity() doesn't work.

Comment: PlaceholderFragment.this.getActivity()